# Showing $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^n P(X >x)=0$

Tags: probability, limits

Hello I am trying to self-teach myself probability by follow a lecture course and example sheets. However, I am completely stuck on the following problem.

Let X be a real-valued random variable. Suppose that the moment-generating function
$m(\theta) = E(e^{\theta X})$ is finite for some $θ > 0$. Show that for $\forall n > 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^n P(X > x) = 0$.

My attempt :  I am not even sure how I should use the moment-generating function in relation to the limit. The only step I can see so far is $P(X > x)  = 1 - F(x)$.

Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Update:

Using Markov Inequality for the variable $e^{\theta X}$ which is non negative random I can say $P(e^{\theta X} \geq x) \leq \frac{E(e^{\theta X})}{x}$  which is a much better place to start. The answer is below for those who don't want spoilers.

Comment: Apply Markov inequality to the random variable $e^{\theta X}$ to get an upper bound of $P[X>x]$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews $x \mapsto e^{\theta x}$ is a non-negative function. You should adress your comment to Hamdiken.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan ah, I was thinking you were starting from $E(X^n)\geq x^n P(X>x).$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews You should read more carefully what is written, namely `Apply Markov inequality to the random variable $\exp(\theta X)$' before voting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea!

First, for $\theta > 0$, notice

$$P(X \geq x) = P(\theta X \geq \theta x) = P(e^{\theta X} \geq e^{\theta x})$$

Of course, as you've noticed, we can apply Markov's inequality to learn that

$$P(e^{\theta X} \geq c) \leq \frac{E(e^{\theta X})}{c} = \frac{m(\theta)}{c}$$

But now for $c = e^{\theta x}$ we see

$$x^n P(X \geq x) = x^n P(e^{\theta X} \geq e^{\theta x}) \leq x^n \frac{m(\theta)}{e^{\theta x}}$$

But now we use the last fact: For some $\theta^*$, we know $m(\theta^*) < \infty$. If we evaluate this identity at $\theta^*$, then, we see

$$x^n P(X \geq x) \leq m(\theta^*) \frac{x^n}{e^{\theta^*x}}$$

which obviously goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, say, by L'hospital's rule.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Wow thank you for the help. I was getting lost in using the expansion of the exponential function.  It turned out to be clever use of the inequality itself. Thank you again